# Constructing the optical centre point according to given conditions

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, physics

> If we are given the focal length value and also the distance of three collinear points ($A,B,C$ with $AB= BC= 2$ cm , $AC= 4$cm) from focal plane is given  and its images from the respective focal plane too ($A'B' =3$cm, $B'C'= 6$cm) . Is it possible to find the optical centre of the lens by construction ? Is it unique?

- Note:  The values are not given except the distance between points. I just want a method you may assume any values

Comment: If we add to given data focal length and distances from focal plane we can plot lines A-B-C and A'-B'-C', then we can find optical centre by construction. It will be not unique because we can 1) translate all construction along the lens; 2) mirror all construction with respect to perpendicular to the lens (if A-B-C is not perpendicular to the lens).

Comment: Nice point , can you tell the method how you would obtain the image and object line ? (The constructiom detail) as answer to this question @IvanKaznacheyeu

Comment: I'm not sure about if it is what you're asking. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNiia.png GJ is focal length, AI, BH, CG are distances from A,B,C to focal plane. First you can take any point A such that distance from A to the lens is equal AI+GJ. Then you can construct right triangle ABL with leg AL = AI – BH (there are 2 possible locations for B if A-B-C is not perpendicular to the lens). Then you can recover all construction from picture. You can do the same for A', B', C' and find point M'. Then you can translate A', B', C' construction along the lens in such way that M' will coincide with M.